# How can I take a medical check in Paris without any visa and insurance program?

Tags: france, health-insurance, medical

I'm now in Paris and want to obtain a medical certificate in order to go to Belarus (it is mandatory to submit a medical document to attend school in Belarus).

However, I don't have a visa here and have no official residence, and thus I don't join any medical program in France.

It is health check and needs tests such as HIV and diabetes.

How can I take the medical test as a traveler and what is the approximate cost of taking it in Paris?

Answer (score 1):

As a tourist in France, without health insurance, you simple pay the bill of the doctor.

Going to a local doctor, that speaks your language, togeather with a printout of what is needed would seem to me the best way to find out what it costs.

As to you being in France without a visa, when you need a visa, is something that should **also** be asked in the travel forum.

https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions